# Technology stack behind YouTrack and TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, youtrack

I would love to know the technology stacks behind YouTrack and TeamCity. Their UX is pretty good.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the implementation of proprietary software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

YouTrack is built using [JetBrains MPS](http://www.jetbrains.com/mps/), so one can expect a heavy use of DSLs inside for database access, web layer and other routine tasks. DSLs are compiled into Java/JS. There is an interesting [case study](https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/mps/MPS_YouTrack_case_study.pdf) document, where developers are summarizing their experience with MPS during YouTrack development.

YouTrack uses custom in-house nosql solution as a persistence backend. I was always woundering if they're planning to release it as open source.

From a web layer perspective I found nothing unexpected: JQuery + ton of custom javascript on top of it. Rest API is powered by Oracle Jersey.

As for deployment, one can either run a JAR file, which has an embedded Jetty container inside, or deploy the application inside a Servlet container.

(information is taken from the public sources: articles, conference talks, webinars, etc)

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this answer, JetBrains did indeed open source their db, [Xodus](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus).